# What does object @object mean

Tags: c#, keyword

I've been playing around with events and delegates and need to raise my event asynchronously, thus I've been using:

```
public event EventHandler OnHelloEvent;

public void Raise()
{
    IAsyncResult syncResult = OnHelloEvent.BeginInvoke(this, new EventArgs(), null, null)
```

In Intellisense, the last `null` is stated to be `object @object`. I haven't come across this before and can't seem to find any documentation for it.

What does this mean? Is it useful?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx: *"Keywords are predefined reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example,* `@if` *is a legal identifier but* `if` *is not because it is a keyword."*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `@` sign can be thought of as "escape" character of sorts.  Since `object` is a keyword in C#, you cannot use it as a variable name.  However prefix it with an `@` character and it no longer is a keyword, just a valid variable name!

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

@ allows you to use reserved keywords as the name of a parameter.

Answer (score 6):

That is the special character for escaping reserved words so that they can be used as identifiers.

See [Section 2.4.2 of the specification](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%2520language%2520specification.doc&ei=grS6TuT0J8XYgQfC3L3pCA&sa=X&oi=unauthorizedredirect&ct=targetlink&ust=1320860554655656&usg=AFQjCNE3EE5fr4OdAT9xPGXKtMkwFUa78A).

Answer (score 4):

Everyone answered "What does this mean?" but nobody answered "Is it useful?"

In most cases, the answer is **No**.  You should *not* use this.

There are a few special exceptions.  Off the top of my head:

1. Interoperability issues with someone else's code: Someone else's code requires you to have a variable with a name of a reserved word.  Maybe their code was written in a language with different reserved words than C#.
2. Computer-generated code: It doesn't *hurt* to use an @ symbol.  If you're paranoid about reserved word collisions, you might decide that all variables in your computer-generated code will use an @ symbol.  Or maybe you are allowing a non-C# program to generate C# programs via a scripting language or whatever and you want to support variables named `class`.

Answer (score 0):

The @ symbol is just a prefix which allows you to use a reserved identifier as a variable name.

So `object @object`, defines a variable of type object called object.